# Using the same UIInterfaceOrientation for all UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

Right now any new `UIViewController` added to my storyboard needs to have a class that has the following code:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

Which is fine to maintain via copy/paste on each class, but is that really necessary? Is there not a faster way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the supported interface orientations across the whole app in the info.plist file using the Supported interface orientations key (you can also set this graphically in the project summary panel).

If that doesn't help (which it apparently doesn't from your comment below) you could add your code as a category on UIViewController, thereby saving you from having to copy and paste it into every controller.

If that seems a bit radical, you could instead create a UIViewController subclass containing that method and use it as the superclass for all of your other controllers (BaseViewController would be a good name for it).

Comment: The summary pane only has the landscape orientations toggled, and the info.plist matches. Could it be an option in interface builder? The only way to fix it so far is by adding the code from my *question*.

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer with some alternative suggestions that may be more use to you.